# Javascript animation left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First I want to thank anybody who will help me. Now let's get started.
I made a kind of a slide menu (at least that's what it is for me). So for me it is almost complete. I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bogdan90i/m9bevmbg/5/)

The only thing I'm having problem with is:

Normally I set it to go -100% to the left if the left button is pressed and stop if the div `(class*-100)`. For example, if I have 3 divs with class "google" then it would be `3*-100= -300%`.
This all is ok, it takes the right values.

But the only thing is that it only goes until -200% and then stops and does not go to -300%. Normally, since it's `if left < -300%` it should at least reach -300%. Also manually put it to -500% (the left value) in the if condition and still it did not work. Only if i set it to -1000% but then it goes too far over.
Can you look at the JSFiddle and help me find a solution please?
Normally how the JSFiddle is setup now it should go 3 times to the left but it does not work. To the right it works just fine.

Comment: Could you please update your JSFiddle so it actually works out of the box? It would be also very helpful if you posted the relevant code in your question, rather than completely relying on an external resource for this.

Comment: Sorry about that, i forgot to set the JQuery 2.2.3 :) not it works as described in the post.

Answer (score 0):

So i found a workaround.
Here is the 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bogdan90i/m9bevmbg/)

```
var totalProject = $('.trape-move-left .proiect-numbering').length;

var projectViews = Math.round($('.trape-move-left').width() / $('.trape-move-left .proiect-numbering').width());
var current_proiect = 0;
$('.left-proiecte-arrowz').click(function() {
    if (projectViews + (current_proiect + 1) <= totalProject) {
      $('.trape-move-left').animate({
        'marginLeft': "-=100%" //moves left
      });
      current_proiect++;
    };
  });
  $('.right-proiecte-arrowz').click(function() {

    if (current_proiect > 0) {
      $('.trape-move-left').animate({
        'marginLeft': "+=100%" //moves left
      });
      current_proiect--;
    };
  });
```